# Default Guake tab names

Tags: guake

I recently installed an update to Guake that sets the tab names to `<user>@<computer-name>/path/to/current/directory/`.

This is rather annyoing when a single tab takes up all the space because of extreme nesting, for example in a Java project (`parent-module/sub-module/src/main/java/no/whirlwin/sample_app/domain/wares/interfaces`).

Earlier the names were something like `tab:0`, `tab:1` or so, which was perfect.

Now I have to manually rename each and every new tab I open, which is a pain in the a...wk.

Other than downgrading to an earlier version, is it possible to change the default tab names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you need to turn `use_vte_titles` off (set to false) in the [gconf schema](https://gitorious.org/guake/guake/blobs/master/data/guake.schemas?p=guake:guake.git;a=blob;f=data/guake.schemas) for guake. Otherwise you can hack custom strings or behaviour in by changing the `on_terminal_title_changed` function or code higher up the call stack, since it is not called consistently. It can be found in the main [guake file](https://gitorious.org/guake/guake/blobs/master/src/guake).

Comment: The link to gconf schema is broken.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a problem of Guake, it is how your terminal title is setup. The new version of Guake respects terminal title from the shell. I bet that you are also getting same long title in Gnome Terminal.
Check how to configure terminal title from your shell:
http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Xterm-Title.html

Comment: You are correct. I haven't used a regular terminal emulator in years.

Answer (score 4):

In retrospect, I found that the easiest way is by running:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/guake/general/use_vte_titles --type boolean false
```

from the command line.

Answer (score 4):

Or edit like this:

```
$ vim `which guake`
```

find the 1000 line and change this:

```
    self.tabs.get_children()[page].set_label(vte.get_window_title())
```

on this:

```
    if self.tabs.get_children()[page].get_label().find('!') != 0:
        self.tabs.get_children()[page].set_label(vte.get_window_title())
    else:
        return
```

And now you can rename your tabs permanently by adding '!' before name, like:

```
!PROD
!backend
!PENTAGON ROOTED
```

Comment: doesn't work for me : could you explain how is `self.tabs.get_children()[page].get_label()` saved between tab closures, or anything ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think, it is too old source for current version of guake

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Alexandar's reply: The following two questions show how to configure a "very short" prompt shortener, which will be also respected by Guake:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/3497885/946850

[Abbreviated current directory in shell prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26844/19205)

I use a "not so short" shortener for myself, my `.bashrc` contains the following:

```
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1X=$(pwd | sed -r "s-^$HOME/--;s-^$HOME-~-;s-^(.[^/]*)/.*/-\1/.../-")'
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}"'$PS1X'"\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

Only the first and the last path component is shown, like the following:

`$HOME` -> `~`

`$HOME/some/deep/sub/dir` -> `some/.../dir`

`/usr/local/deeply/inside/there` -> `/usr/.../there`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this line in the source code, I noticed there's another config entry that can be helpful: `max-tab-name-length`. I used `dconf-editor` to set it to 32, and it saved my sanity.

https://github.com/Guake/guake/blob/18a79ea8e4c1d53d357211e8e3d05509b9927cd1/guake/utils.py#L119