# Where does guake put it user preferences?

Tags: debian, gsettings, guake

Previously guake used to have its preferences stored in

```
~/.gconf/apps/guake/general
```

but with move to gtk3 it has moved to gsettings and dconf . While dconf-editor does show me the preferences with the toggle switch I'm unable to figure out where it actually stays.

Comment: Are you asking about the dconf database file? `~/.config/dconf/user`?

Comment: wow, thank you , saw that it's some sort of binary file. 

`~/.config/dconf$ file user
user: GVariant Database file, version 0`

Answer (score 5):

A direct way:

```bsh
# save settings
guake --save-preferences ~/Downloads/guake_prefs

# load settings
guake --restore-preferences ~/Downloads/guake_prefs
```

---

Another way my experience, on Ubuntu 20.04,

```bsh
# save the config file
dconf save /apps/guake/ > Downloads/guake.dconf

# load
dconf load /apps/guake/ < Downloads/guake.dconf
```

You can also install **dconf-editor** for an UI editor.

```bsh
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y dconf-editor
```

Then you open dconf Editor and choose the config options of guake at `/apps/guake/`.

Comment: And the tab titles are stored in `/home/<user>/.config/guake/session.json` (at least on Ubuntu 22.04), which come into effect once you disable the `use_vte_titles` option: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45670/34492

Answer (score 1):

Here's the command to dump just the guake-related configuration:

```
dconf dump /apps/guake/
```

The output should look something like this:

```
[general]
prompt-on-quit=true
window-height=46
mouse-display=true
window-width=100
max-tab-name-length=100
window-losefocus=true
quick-open-enable=false
history-size=1000
open-tab-cwd=true
window-tabbar=true
window-halignment=0
quick-open-command-line='gvim %(file_path)s'
compat-delete='delete-sequence'
scroll-keystroke=true
abbreviate-tab-names=true
display-n=0
use-audible-bell=false
use-default-font=true
scroll-output=true
use-scrollbar=true
use-trayicon=true
set-window-title=true
use-popup=true
window-refocus=false
use-vte-titles=true

[keybindings/global]
show-hide='F12'

[style]
cursor-shape=0
cursor-blink-mode=2

[style/background]
transparency=100

[style/font]
allow-bold=true
palette='#000000000000:#999900000000:#0000a6a60000:#999999990000:#00000000b2b2:#b2b20000b2b2:#0000a6a6b2b2:#bfbfbfbfbfbf:#666666666666:#e5e500000000:#0000d9d90000:#e5e5e5e50000:#00000000ffff:#e5e50000e5e5:#0000e5e5e5e5:#e5e5e5e5e5e5:#000000000000:#ffffffffdddd'
palette-name='Custom'
```

This can be saved to a file and loaded again later.

```
dconf dump /apps/guake/ > dconf-guake-dump.txt
# Later:
dconf load /apps/guake/ < dconf-guake-dump.txt
```

Comment: But how to restore it?

Comment: @Anh-ThiDINH See the `dconf load` command in the edited answer.