# bash prompt with abbreviated current director including dot files?

Tags: bash, prompt

I have the following in my .bash_profile (from a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/abbreviated-current-directory-in-shell-prompt) here:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='pwd2=$(sed "s:\([^/]\)[^/]*/:\1/:g" <<<$PWD)'
PS1='\u@\h:$pwd2\$ '
```

However, if the current directory is within a .dir (such as ~/.vim/bundle/) then the prompt just displays a .:

```
chris@DeathStar:/U/c/./bundle$
```

I would like it instead to retain 1 char for all dirnames unless it has a dot, in which case it would show two, like this:

```
chris@DeathStar:/U/c/.v/bundle$
```

Even better would be if I also have the home directory represented by a `~` like this:

```
chris@DeathStar:~/.v/bundle$
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it OK just putting the basename of the current working directory in the prompting instead of the whole directory, and use `pwd` command if you want to get the whole directory? That means use `\W` instead `\w`. This solution is simple and work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the trick, adding an optional `.` to the capture:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='pwd2=$(sed "s:\(\.\?[^/]\)[^/]*/:\1/:g" <<<$PWD)'
PS1='\u@\h:$pwd2\$ '
```

And for the 'even better':

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='pwd2=$(sed -e "s:$HOME:~:" -e "s:\(\.\?[^/]\)[^/]*/:\1/:g" <<<$PWD)'
PS1='\u@\h:$pwd2\$ '
```

Comment: hmmm...neither of these work on my system: the prompt shows the full dirnames in the path ... `chris@DeathStar:/Users/chris/db/personal$`

Comment: Hmm. Could be an incompatibility between gnu sed and osx sed. Don't have an osx machine to test on.

Comment: Thank you! That pointed me in the right direction... installed gnu-sed and all it works!