# Bash prompt configuration

Tags: bash, prompt, bashrc

I've recently switched to Parrot linux and I'm very happy with it, but there's just one thing, this default fancy bash prompt is really ugly. 
I used zsh before, and for some reasons I want to go back to bash but I'd love
to get the same prompt "theme" that I had with zsh, whish was very sober.

[image: zsh "fishy" theme]

I especially like the way it only display the first character of the directories names in the path except the current one.

I'm searching how I could write this in the .bashrc but I'm not finding anything.

Comment: It did, thanks a lot and sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing heavily from [Dennis Kaarsemaker's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55935/117549):

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='_abbrev_pwd=$(sed -e "s:$HOME:~:" -e "s:/\(.\)[^/]*:/\1:g" <<< "$(dirname "$PWD")")/"$(basename "$PWD")"'
PS1='\u@\h ${_abbrev_pwd}> '
```

The PROMPT_COMMAND variable is a [special bash variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#Bash-Variables) that is executed each time a prompt is about to be printed. The code here sets a variable named `_abbrev_pwd` to the concatenation of the following elements:

- the output of a sed command: `$(sed -e ... <<< ...)`
- a forward slash `/`
- the "current" directory: `$(basename "$PWD")`

The sed command itself takes a here-string as input; that here-string is the result of calling `dirname "$PWD"` in order to strip off the current directory. That string is then subject to two replacements (given in the `-e` sed options):

1. replace any appearance of your "$HOME" directory with a tilde, and
2. replace any path element (forward slash, a captured single character `.`, then any number of non-forward-slashes) with a forward slash followed by that (captured) single character; repeat that pattern match "globally" with the `g` flag. I've used `:` as the `sed` search & replace delimiter instead of the common `/`, in order to avoid [leaning toothpick syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome) in trying to escape the *desired* forward slashes.

Lastly, we set PS1 to use the `_abbrev_pwd` variable where you would normally put the `$PWD`.